# Extracting text from a file where date -time is the index

Tags: c#, file, directory

I have got around 800 files of maximum 55KB-100KB each where the data is in this format

Date,Time,Float1,Float2,Float3,Float4,Integer

Date is in DD/MM/YYYY format and Time is in the format of HH:MM

Here the date ranges from say 1st May to 1June and each day, the Time varies from 09:00 to 15:30.

I want to run a program so that, for each file, it extracts the data pertaining to a particular given date and writes to a file.

I am trying to get around, to form a to do a search and extract operation. I dont know, how to do it, would like to have some idea.

I have written the code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string destpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        destpath += "\\DIR";
        DirectoryInfo Dest = Directory.CreateDirectory(destpath);
        DirectoryInfo Source = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\IEOD");
        FileInfo[] fiArr = Source.GetFiles("*.csv");
        Console.WriteLine("Search Date:");
        string srchdate = Console.ReadLine();
        String FileNewLine;
        String FileNewdt;
        FileInfo r;
        foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
        {
            r = new FileInfo(destpath + "\\" + f.Name);
            r.Create();
            StreamWriter Sw = r.AppendText();                
            StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(f.FullName);

            while (Sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                FileNewLine = Sr.ReadLine();
                FileNewdt = FileNewLine.Substring(0,10);
                if (String.Compare(FileNewdt, srchdate, true) == 0)
                {
                    //write it to a file;
                    Console.WriteLine(FileNewLine);

                }
            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
```

As of now, it should write into the Console. The writing with the help of StreamWriter will be done later, but I am facing a runtime error. It says, " 'C:\Documents and Settings\Soham Das\Desktop\Test\DIR\ABAN.csv' because it is being used by another process." 
Here ABAN is a newly created file, by the code. The problem is faced at `StreamWriter Sw = r.AppendText()`

Help appreciated.
Thanks
Soham

Comment: I think you should describe the problem a little better. Is each 'date/time/data....' on a separate line? Give us an actual example and is '/' really the field delimiter? You'll probably find that StreamReader, DateTime.TryPase as well as double/int.TryParse will be helpfu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have edited the question to show that the delimiter is actually a comma instead of a slash (which would have conflicted with the date format) this becomes a lot easier. I've re-posted the answer from last night below.

```
// This would come from Stream.ReadLine() or something
string line = "02/06/2010,10:05,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5";

string[] parts = line.Split(',');
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(parts[0], "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(parts[1]);
date = date.Add(time); // adds the time to the date
float float1 = Single.Parse(parts[2]);
float float2 = Single.Parse(parts[3]);
float float3 = Single.Parse(parts[4]);
float float4 = Single.Parse(parts[5]);
int integer = Int32.Parse(parts[6]);

Console.WriteLine("Date: {0:d}", date);
Console.WriteLine("Time: {0:t}", date);
Console.WriteLine("Float1: {0}", float1);
Console.WriteLine("Float2: {0}", float2);
Console.WriteLine("Float3: {0}", float3);
Console.WriteLine("Float4: {0}", float4);
Console.WriteLine("Integer: {0}", integer);
```

Obviously you can make it more resilient by adding error handling, using TryParse, etc. But this should give you a basic idea of how to manipulate strings in .NET.

Comment: If the delimitter was truly a /, and dates were stored as DD/MM/YYYY, then the date would be in 3 parts, requiring a little bit extra work to get it parsed into a variable.

Comment: Thanks Josh,
I apologise, I kind of confused everybody with my earlier question.

Comment: But why am I facing a "cannot edit this file, used by another process" error ?

Comment: My guess is that you forgot to close a stream somewhere. Instead of reading line by line you can probably get away with using File.ReadAllLines and File.WriteAllLines (look them up on MSDN) to read and write the files in one shot.

Comment: I see from your recent edits that you are opening and discarding streams. When you call FileInfo.Create followed by AppendText you are creating two writable Streams to the same file which will not work. Store the return value from Create and write to that instead.

Answer (score 0):

So 800 files with around 100KB sums up to 80 KBytes. So why don't built up a little class like

```
public class Entry
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public float Float1 {get; set;}
    public int Integer1 {get; set;}

    public Entry(string values)
    {
        //ToDo: Parse single line into properties
        //      e.g. use String.Split, RegEx, etc.
    }
}
```

Also you should take care about implementing `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` (there is a good explanation in the book *Essential C#*). And you should add the interface `IComparable` to that class which just makes somethine like

```
public int CompareTo(Entry rhs)
{
    return this.Date.CompareTo(rhs.Date);
}
```

If you got this you can easily do the following:

```
var allEntries = new SortedList<Entry>();

string currentLine = null;

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\MyFile.txt"))
    while ((currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var entry = new Entry(currentLine);
            allEntries.Add(entry);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do whatever you like
            //maybe just
            continue;
            //or
            throw;
        }
    }
```

So what's missing is to read in all the files (instead of a single one). But this can be done by another loop on `Directory.GetFiles()` which maybe itself is looped through a `Directory.GetDirectories()`.

After reading all the files into your List you can do whatever LINQ query comes to your mind.

Comment: Oliver, thanks for the code design, but in essence I wanted how to know the implement the code which is analogous to `Entry()` over here. 

Creating another class, I think its an overkill