# collect text file information using c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file named `abc.txt`. The file have info like this

```
jani
stay in USA
karim
stay in France
fara
stay in UK
```

The code needs to read the file from beginning and read the first line and put it to in a string let `nameString`. Then it read the second line and put the info to a another string let name `addressString`. Then it read the third line and put the info into `nameString` and then forth line and put the info as `addressString`. Like this way it will continue up to the end of file. I have to put those information on anywhere else. So, I need all the name and address in a for loop.

Can anybody pls help me to collect this info.

Thanks in advance
Riad

Comment: riad - I can't really understand what you're after. There is no address in the text file from what you've posted. Could you please tidy up your post for clarity?

Comment: answered nearly the same question twenty minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955027/extracting-text-from-a-file-where-date-time-is-the-index/2956589#2956589

Comment: the code need to read the file from beginning and read the first line and put it to in a string let namString.then it read the second line and put the info to a another string let name addressString.then it read the third line and put the info into nameString and then forth line and put the info as addressString..like this way it will continue upto the end of file...hope u clear now

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: no..i dont get any solution on web..so asking u experts

Comment: @David Neale: dear david. stay in USA. i just mention it as an address. that's not a factor .But i need the first line of a text file in a string and second line in another string.then so so...it will continue upto the end of a file

Comment: @riad: instead of just looking on the web for a solution, what code have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go

```
 StreamReader SR;
 string S;
 SR = File.OpenText(filename);
 S = SR.ReadLine();
 string name = "";
 string address = "";
 counter = 1;
 while (S != null)
 {
    if ((counter % 2) != 0)
       name = S;
    else
       address = S;

    //do what you want with name and address here

    S = SR.ReadLine();
    counter++;

 }
 SR.Close();
```

Make sense?

Comment: I'd be putting the StreamReader in a using statement.

Comment: @Dear DrLazer: Many many thanks bro its working smoothly. but can u do it using separate string name. late name goes to nameString and address goes  to addressString.Because i have to integrate lot of information with this.So,I shall be very much grateful to you do it using separate string.I shall be happy if you do it using a for loop ..anyway thanks..

Comment: @DrLazer: dear can you pls do it for me??

Comment: I've updated the example a little - I'm sure you can mange from here

Comment: sorry bro its not working fine. if u set two on //do what u want Console.WriteLine(name); and Console.WriteLine(address); then you see the output is not continuous.its showing discontinuous result..

Comment: ohh...bro...i already try to shuffle it.but still discontinuous result....anyway thanks for your nice effort.You do a lot for me.I can make it proper .thanks a lot.  ....riad

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out how to read from text files in c#
Here is a resource for you:

http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx

Also you will need to figure out how to manipulate the strings you read in.
A resource for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28VS.71%29.aspx

good luck I'm sure you will get there

Comment: thanks bro... i know how to read and write from a file.But i need 
the code need to read the file from beginning and read the first line and put it to in a string let namString.then it read the second line and put the info to a another string let name addressString.then it read the third line and put the info into nameString and then forth line and put the info as addressString..like this way it will continue upto the end of file...hope u understand..thanks again..pls give me a solution